# Why Firmata Test doesn't allow me to choose a port?

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm a beginner and, sorry, also I don't speak English very well. However, I'm going to try to explain my problem. 
I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04.2 and Arduino Uno R3. 
I downloaded Firmata Test binaries for Linux 64 bit, I gave it permissions with `chmod 754 <file>`. Also I uploaded StandardFirmata from Arduino IDE to the board. Afterwards, I quit Arduino IDE and ran Firmata Test with `./file`. But, the Port menu has no items within. I tried restarting the board and the application as well.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

If your user does not have access to serial ports, rather than running an application as root with sudo, try giving your user the appropriate permissions by adding to the dialout group before you run it.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/112568/how-do-i-allow-a-non-default-user-to-use-serial-device-ttyusb0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I ran it as:
sudo ./file